# Does an algebraic closure of $F_p$ contain an element of infinite (multiplicative) order?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, roots-of-unity, splitting-field

I am trying to find (as many as possible) elements in the algebraic closure of a positive characteristic field, being roots of irreducible polynomial inside some splitting field which are not roots of unity (which are not $k$-th roots of unity for any $k$).
By "as many as possible" I mean I am looking for positive results on the existence of irreducible polynomials having such roots in a splitting field, like for instance ensuring one in each degree...

But proving there is one such element would already be very good for me.

Comment: Note that there is a slight disconnect between your title and your question. While $\mathbb{F}_p$ is certainly a positive characteristic field, not every positive characteristic field is finite or an algebraic extension of a finite field. For instance, $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$ is a positive characteristic field, and this field already contains elements that are not roots of unity (e.g., $x$ itself).

Comment: Right, ideally I would need the existence for any field of positive characteristic, and the hardest case of course were finite fields. That is why the title was focused on them. I am trying to find polynomials that cannot divide polynomials of type $x^m-x^n, m\neq n$, but now I know this is hopeless

Comment: Do. Not. Post. Comments as answers.

Comment: Looko at the field of rational functions $\Bbb{F}_p(x)$ to find a field of characteristic $p$ that has elements of infinite order. Such an element is necessarily transcendental over $\Bbb{F}_p$, and is thus not contained in the algebraic closure $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Every element $\theta$ of the algebraic closure of a finite field $F$ is algebraic over $F$ and so has finite degree over $F$ and thus lies in a finite extension of $F$. This extension is a finite field and so $\theta$ is a root of unity.